# How can I fetch the pic url (ex. pic.twitter.com/ABC) from the `media_id` (ex. `12345`) on Twitter's API?

Tags: json, twitter

When I upload media via Twitter's [media/upload](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) endpoint, it returns the following json:

```
{
  "media_id": 1234567890987654321,
  "media_id_string": "1234567890987654321",
  "size": 12345,
  "image": {
    "w": 1234,
    "h": 1234,
    "image_type": "image/jpeg"
  }
}
```

Given the above, how can I fetch the associated media url (ex. `pic.twitter/com/ABCDEFG_HIJK`) after `media/upload`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly - that's not how the API works.

The process is

1. Upload image
2. Get media ID
3. Post a new Tweet and include the media ID
4. The new tweet will have an image URL in it